# Can I get timezone offset or timezone name with gmlib in delphi?

Tags: delphi, gmlib

I'm using GMlib_1.2.4 with Delphi 7 and XE5 for getting LatLon, works great. Can I also use it to get timezone offset or name? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to provide more details, maybe a code example of what you've done so far. Actually show that you've done some research on your own to try to solve this.

Comment: The Google Maps API doesn't return this information, therefore neither GMLib :-)